# NoVNC, The function of hidden password field

Tags: jquery, passwords, vnc, novnc

I have a simple question about noVNC application. I've been learning about noVNC for days and want to used it for having fun because its looks interesting, remote through web browser.
the question is, when i try to editing the file called *vnc.html* . i found a password dialog that can be insert in. but when i run the noVNC, i cannot find the password dialog. when i inspect it, its visibility was hidden. I want to try to make noVNC safer by using that password dialog. please tell me

**how i can use that password dialog ?**

Thanks a lot for your time and your respond!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VNC password is set at the VNC server. The password dialog is hidden until the server requests a password. Many Linux based VNC servers have a `vncpasswd` command for setting the password.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the respond @kanaka . I will gonna try it.